# Web API multiple or single call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We are re-writing our system using MVC 4.0 and web API and we are currently at a decision splitter.

Would it be more efficient / best practice to do multiple small calls to a Web API rather than one single large one for displaying data on an MVC webpage:-

ie

**Multiple calls** :

call 1 - returns core data about a user (user model)

call 2 - returns data regarding a users status (status model)

call 3 - returns user history ( history model)

**Single call** :
returns a Full ViewModel that includes all the core data about a user, his current status and a list of history items

```
  public string UserName { get;set;}
  public Status UserStatus { get;set;}
  public List<history> { get;set;}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated (additional info, each one of the calls is a separate database call)

Comment: Will the consumers of this API *always* perform all 3 calls, *often* perform all 3 calls, or *sometimes* perform all 3 calls?

Comment: for the current User page, then yes, all 3 calls, but to answer your question, then id envisige that user details could be called seperatly also,  so "Sometimes"

Comment: It is really down to the opinion of the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not certain this is the best place for this question (I think this may fall more into the Programmers area), I would say that it really depends on what data you need most often. If you need the whole object for every page in your app, then really is it going to save you anything to make multiple small calls? If some of that data can be cached on the client side, then maybe a lot of small calls would be more efficient, but otherwise, you're increasing the amount of client (client has to retrieve, parse, and then output three streams of data) and server (where the call has to be routed, data retrieved, and data returned) work for little benefit.

Secondly, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever points out, there's the question of outsiders calling this API. If the API is public, or called by multiple apps, it's a question of what is the most efficient package that /most/ apps will need, not just what this app needs. If /most/ apps will need the whole object, then it doesn't make sense to give them calls to retrieve only pieces of that object. If they only need, say, Status, then an API method for just retrieving Status is a good call.

Answer (score 0):

When you are designing an API action always think about performance, how many times in a second your action will be consumed, does your separate operation is taking too long to respond. Make simple benchmarks for each operation by using `Stopwatch`, then make several parallel calls to see if any operation makes bottleneck.

In my opinion every action should be simple and atomic.